# Do popular series like One Piece not take part in popularity polls in Bakuman?

Tags: bakuman

In the anime *Bakuman*, several real-world mangas were mentioned and one of them was *One Piece*. We saw that in the popularity polls, only the series made by the characters present in the anime taking part. I am saying this because we saw Eiji Nizuma in the first place for more than 20 times in a row.

Now, taking the real-world into consideration, and the fact that *One Piece* is still ongoing (so are some other series), it is very likely that those will hog the upper places.

So how come do we not only see a single character dominate the first place, but all subsequent characters taking the place below first (referring to season 3)? Is it that long-running and popular series do not take part in the polls (although that'd be a controversy since Mashiro's uncle had his manga dropped, not mentioning other problems that would bring forward)?

Comment: IRL they do take part in the ranking system, the line-up of every issue goes according to the surveys from the last issue, since One Piece is usually ranked pretty high, most of the time is one the first mangas that get featured in evenry issue. While less popular series get buried down to the last pages of the magazine. I always took the Bakuman universe to be an AU or future world where the series we know have all finished and it's all manga by the new blood mangakas the series is about.